# Show multiple product categories woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to display multiple product categories on the shopping page.

For instance if I open the following url:

```
woocommerce/?product_cat=shirts
```

This will show me all the shirts. well thats nice, but I also only like to see all the blue shirts.

```
woocommerce/?product_cat=blue
```

What file do I need to edit to make me select multiple categories? or should I select multiple product categories an other way?

I was looking for a solution like this:

```
woocommerce/?product_cat=shirts|blue
```

the link would be changed from a form on top of the shopping page with check boxes. I think that would make a very nice way of sorting products.

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution that you looking for:

```
?product_cat=shirts+blue
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's your solution mate

```
[product_categories number="" orderby="name" hide-empty="1" parent="0"]
```

Comment: If you feel this is the correct answer, please explain why.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for my case was [https://findfitness.store/shop/?product_cat=accessories,electronics-gadgets,category3](https://findfitness.store/shop/?product_cat=accessories,electronics-gadgets)

Where:

- accessories
- electronics-gadgets
- category3

Are the `slugs` of the various categories.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:
`https://example.com/product-category/cat1,cat2/`

note that the page title will be the first category specified in the URL.

Tested and works in woocomerce 6.1.1 and Wordpress: 5.9